# CMake library targets don't always appear in Visual Studio 2017's Startup Item dropdown

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017

I am currently working on a CMake C++ project, using Visual Studios new-ish built-in support for CMake:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/10/05/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/

My "root" CMakeLists.txt file sets a few variables and then includes a number of subdirectories:

```
project("MyProject")
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.3)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(projecta/include)
include_directories(projectb/include)
include_directories(projectc/include)

# Dump the DEBUG and RELEASE outputs next to the program
# that will use the DLL
set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../lib")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../lib")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../dll")

set(CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../lib")
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../lib")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/../dll")

add_subdirectory(projecta)
add_subdirectory(projectb)
add_subdirectory(projectc)
```

The `projecta`, `projectb` and `projectc` subdirectories contain simple CMakeLists.txt files that look like:

```
set(LIB_NAME "projectc")
set(LIB_DEPENDENCIES "projecta" "projectb")

include_directories(include)

FILE(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_CPP_FILES "src/*.cpp")
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_C_FILES "src/*.c")
FILE(GLOB_RECURSE HEADER_FILES "include/"${LIB_NAME}"/*.h")

add_library(${LIB_NAME} ${PLT_LIBRARY_MODE} ${SOURCE_CPP_FILES} ${SOURCE_C_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})
target_link_libraries(${LIB_NAME} ${LIB_DEPENDENCIES})
```

I open the project from the developer console:

```
devenv <the directory containing the top CMakeLists.txt file>
```

MY PROBLEM: The shared libraries defined by `add_libraries` do not appear as targets under "Select Startup Item", which prevents me from being able to compile using F7 when I am in one of the target's .cpp files.

- Selecting "Current Document" under "Select Startup Item" has no effect - F7 or Ctrl-Shift-B don't work. I'm not sure what the rules are for making this feature available.
- I have seen such DLLs appear there before, but I haven't been able to pin down what was different in my other CMakeLists.txt files (I don't have them anymore)
- If I include a third-party library's `CMakeLists.txt` using `add_subdirectory`, its .exe targets appear under "Select Startup Item" and I can use F7 on them.
- If I right-click on the top-level CMakeLists.txt file, I can see all of the DLL, LIB and EXE targets under "Build". This is how I am compiling now, but it isn't as satisfying as mashing F7 ;)

Anybody out there run into similar problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that my environment/cache might have been corrupted. I deleted the auto-generated .vs folder in my project directory and reopened the project using 
 `devenv .`, as before.

I am now able to build any cpp file using F7. Still unable to see any DLL target under Select Startup Item, but this is good enough for now.

EDIT: Alternatively, CMake/Cache/Generate/CMakeLists.txt seems to help too.

Comment: And also make sure you upgrade to 15.3 with more CMake related fixes.

Comment: Thanks - that changed the behavior a lot. Still wish I could define a default build for dll targets (so I can mash F7 from anywhere), still no success there though.